# Django 1.8 handwritten form no POST data

Tags: django, django-forms

I've become very frustrated by a problem I'm having. I have a large form that's hand-written (not using Django's forms), and am simply trying to access the data from the inputs in the views (in that case, some inputs were posting, others weren't).

Leaving the specifics of that form aside for now since there are too many things at play, in my troubleshooting process I wrote the simplest form I could think of, and am now getting no POST data besides the csrf_token.

I have no idea why this would be, since something similar (and much more complex) works fine on several other django projects I'm running. For this example, I tried with action="" as well to no avail. Is there something incredibly obvious I'm missing?

Here's the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 
<head> 
</head> 
 
<body> 
<form method="POST" id="theForm" action="/simpleForm/">{% csrf_token %} 
        <input type="text" id="theText" value="Where am I?" /> 
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" value="I don't exist" /> 
        <input type="submit" /> 
 
</form> 
 
</body> 
 
</html>
```

Here is a simple view checking for data:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def simpleForm(request):

    if (request.method == 'POST'):

        print('In post')
        print(request.POST)

        for i in request.POST.keys():

            print('key: {0} value: {1}'.format(i, request.POST[i]))

        return render(request, 'simpleForm.html')

    else:

        return render(request, 'simpleForm.html')
```

Comment: How did you verify there is no POST data?

Comment: Hello Rohan, @Mark Galloway already gave the answer, but I know there's no data because I was printing information from the request.POST object, check my view code above. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the 'name' attribute of the  tags in your HTML form. Without those, Django will not add them to request.POST

```
<form method="POST" id="theForm" action="/simpleForm/">{% csrf_token %} 
        <input type="text" id="theText" name="mytext" value="Where am I?" /> 
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" name="myhidden" value="I don't exist" /> 
        <input type="submit" />
```

Comment: Oh my God! I knew it would be something insanely simple! Thank you very much.

Comment: It is not Django that is not adding them here, but the browser. Quite simply, if they don't have name attributes, the browser will not include them in any posted data.